# What is this red X icon showing in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, certificate, email-client

I just noticed this icon I have never seen before in Thunderbird and I am wondering what it is:

[image]

Hovering over it doesn't tell me anything. Can anyone provide any insight?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Icons in this place show that the message was encrypted and/or digitally signed using S/MIME.

The red cross icon means that there's a problem with the certificate used to sign this message (e.g. it was expired, or otherwise cannot be verified). Click on the envelope to see the details.

Comment: Textbook example of why tooltips are important!